# SystemVerilog- How to write a constructor with initialization?

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

I have the following transaction:

```
typedef enum {READ = 0, WRITE = 1} direction_enum;

//Transaction

class axi_transaction extends uvm_sequence_item();
   bit id = 0;  //const
   bit [31:0] addr;
   bit [2:0]  size = 0'b100;//const
   direction_enum rw;
   bit [31:0] transfers [$];



   //factory registration
   `uvm_object_utils_begin(axi_transaction)
   `uvm_field_int(id, UVM_ALL_ON)
   `uvm_field_int(addr, UVM_ALL_ON)
   `uvm_field_int(size, UVM_ALL_ON)
   `uvm_field_enum(rw, UVM_ALL_ON)
   `uvm_field_int(transfers, UVM_ALL_ON)      
   `uvm_object_utils_end  

   //constructor
   function new(string name = "axi_transaction");
      super.new(name);
   endfunction: new

endclass: axi_transaction
```

I want to extend the new function, so I can initializes the transaction in the sequence with arguments which initialize some of the transaction members (like addr, transfers) by:

```
 ax_trx =  axi_transaction::type_id::create();
```

How to write the constructor of the transaction and how do I initialize the transaction from the sequencer?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot add arguments to the class constructor when using the UVM factory. In general this is not good OOP programing practice for re-use because if you do add arguments to either the base class or extended class, you have to modify every place where the class gets constructed.

A better option is to use the uvm_config_db or set the individual fields you need to after constructing the object.

```
ax_trx =  axi_transaction::type_id::create(); 
ax_trx.addr = some_address
ax_trx.transfers = '{word1,word2,word3};
```

Comment: @dave_59- can you give me example?

Comment: I don't get your point about constructor arguments not being good OOP programming practice. Of course adding new arguments is going to break user code, but the same goes for passing stuff via the config DB or setting variables directly. There's no workaround for modifying client code if a class's dependencies change.

Comment: The point of inheritance and polymorphism is to be able to extend functionality of objects without disturbing the code using the those extended objects. The same is true for creating transactions. Instead of using methods with longs lists of arguments, we put those arguments into a transaction, and extend the transaction as needed.

Comment: @dave_59- I'm new to uvm_config_db. Can you explain me for example how should I pass the queue from the sequence to the transaction by uvm_config_db?

Comment: I think for you the easiest thing would be to set the individual fields after creating the object. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use uvm_config_db class for initialisation.

You can set the value using following syntax. And then you can get that value inside the constructor of that class.

```
uvm_config_db#(int)::set(this,“my_subblock_a”,“max_cycles”,max_cycles)
uvm_config_db#(int)::get(this,“”, “max_cycles”,max_cycles)
```

For more information of "uvm_config_db", you can refer to the following paper.
https://www.synopsys.com/Services/Documents/hierarchical-testbench-configuration-using-uvm.pdf

Comment: according the paper the "get" should be. I didn't see any "get" in the constructor.

Comment: "get" and "set" methods are static methods of uvm_config_db class. And you can use "get" method anywhere, as long as the require variable is set with "set" method